# How to disable drawer layout from peeking on long press?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have a DrawerLayout and right now when you long press near the edge of the screen it peeks out from the edge of the screen a few pixels.
How do I disable it from showing when long pressing near the edge?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Please edit your question to add [**sample data**](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. Provide them as [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and strictly [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **DO NOT** post code or additional information in comments. Please ensure you have a [**minimal, complete and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).